# Angular4: Using HttpClient's interceptor to setup a spinner

Tags: angular

Here the interceptor I've written to handle the spinner directly via the interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private _globalSpinnerService: GlobalSpinnerService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const spinnerParam: string = req.params.get("spinner")
        let handleObs: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(req)
        if(spinnerParam) {
            this._globalSpinnerService.spinner = true
            handleObs.toPromise().then(() => {
                this._globalSpinnerService.spinner = false
            })
        }

        return handleObs
    }
}
```

It's working as expected. However, I now see all my requests involving the spinner getting sent twice. So I guess my way to remove the spinner isn't the neatest. How can I tell my interceptor to remove my spinner once the handle is over ?

**EDIT:**

I changed the code by replacing my `handleObs.toPromise().then` by `handleObs.do()` and it's now working fine. I am just not sure why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `handleObs` observable is cold, `toPromise` creates a subscription, then `httpClient(...).subscribe` creates another subscription. This results in several requests. And yes, `handleObs.do()` should be used instead, it doesn't result in subscription and just provides side effect.

Generally it is desirable to have request counter for a spinner, because it should handle concurrent requests properly:

```
function spinnerCallback() {
  if (globalSpinnerService.requestCount > 0) 
    globalSpinnerService.requestCount--;
}

if(spinnerParam) {
    globalSpinnerService.requestCount++;
    handleObs.do(spinnerCallback, spinnerCallback);
}
```

And `globalSpinnerService.spinner` is actually a getter:

```
get spinner() {
  this.requestCount > 0;
}
```

Comment: I am indeed using a counter and not a boolean :) it was just to make things even easier but cheers mate !

Comment: In my case using `.do` does not work and my `requestCount` are not decreased.

Comment: @HristoEnev I'd suggest to ask a question with your particular case and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it.

Comment: @estus Sure. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951301/angular-4-callback-for-observable-do-does-not-get-called-in-interceptor

Comment: This great post : https://grensesnittet.computas.com/loading-status-in-angular-done-right/ demonstrates how to achieve this and explains things in details.