# Angular 4 - Callback for Observable.do() does not get called in interceptor

Tags: angular, observable, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

Trying to implement solution for displaying a loading indicator when requests are in progress. Looking from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520889/angular4-using-httpclients-interceptor-to-setup-a-spinner/46523177?noredirect=1#comment80846737_46523177) solution I implemented the interceptor with the service. All works fine, except the counter is not deceasing becase the `.do()` callback never gets executed (`b` is never printed in the console). Any thoughts on that? How to know if request has finished?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { LoadingIndicatorService } from './loading-indicator.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingIndicatorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      this.loadingIndicatorService.requestsCount++;

      const handleObs: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(req);

      console.log('a');
      handleObs.do(() => {
        console.log('b');
        this.loadingIndicatorService.requestsCount--;
      });

      return handleObs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The do() is never fired because you have to return your new observable. you could do it like so:

```
export class LoadingIndicatorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this.loadingIndicatorService.requestsCount++;

  const handleObs: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(req);

  console.log('a');
  return handleObs.do(() => {
    console.log('b');
    this.loadingIndicatorService.requestsCount--;
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I thought only returning the variable will work. But anyway a small modification is that you need to do this on your third callback of `.do()` which is the `complete` callback or you will end up with negative `requestsCount`. Thank you.