# Inject http interceptor at component

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I've created this http interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor  implements HttpInterceptor {
    public my_status: boolean = true;
    private _statusChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    public statusChange$ = this._statusChange.asObservable();
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.changeStatus(false);
        const my_req = req.clone({
            url: API_PATH + req.url
        });
        return next
            .handle(my_req)
            .do(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse)
                    this.changeStatus(true);
            });
    }

    private changeStatus(status: boolean) {
        this.my_status = status;
        this._statusChange.next(this.my_status);
    }
}
```

And in my component, I did it:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public my_status: boolean;
    constructor(private httpInterceptor: NoopInterceptor) {
        this.my_status = httpInterceptor.my_status;
        httpInterceptor.statusChange$.subscribe(this.changeStatus);
    }

    changeStatus(status: boolean) {
        this.my_status = status;
    }

}
```

At `app.module`, I provided the interceptor like this:

```
providers: [
   {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: NoopInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
]
```

When I do in the way above, I get `No provider for NoopInterceptor!`, because I'm not providing `NoopInterceptor`, but if I provide `NoopInterceptor` like this:

```
providers: [
   {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: NoopInterceptor,
        multi: true
    },
    NoopInterceptor
]
```

I'll get two injections and the component will get the wrong one, then I won't be able to subscribe `statusChange`. How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely possible to create single interceptor instance with:

```
providers: [
    NoopInterceptor,
   {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useExisting: NoopInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
]
```

But a proper solution for loading indicator state (I guess `statusChange` serves for this purpose) is to detach it from an interceptor and make it a separate provider.

And as it's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46523177/3731501), there should be request counter because there can be simultaneous requests, and it should be affected by both success and error `do` callbacks.

Comment: No, this is not working. The constructor of the interceptor is getting called twice

Comment: No, it's called once, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxrajv . Any way, as it was noted, a proper way is to store loading state in separate service.

Comment: You suggest making a separate provider. But how should a separate provider know if there is a status change? It would need to inject an interceptor again and will have the same problem as the component? Or am I wrong? I'm reading this suggestion the second time here

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to put NoopInterceptor before the provide of HTTP_INTERCEPTOR and useExisting instead of useClass ?
In that way you should get only one NoopInterceptor instance.