# Angular 4- Show Loader on the load of each page and hide after all the API request is completed

Tags: angular, interceptor, loader

I am working on this angular Project with multiple modules. I am trying to show a loader on a load of each page and only hide the loader once the request for all the API call is completed for that page.
What's happening right now in the project is when a component is loaded then few API calls are made onInit() and some other API calls are made on a load of various services that's been invoked by the component. So, my problem won't be solved just by showing a loader right after onInit is called and hide it after all the request is completed.

With reference from this post - [Angular HTTP Interceptor - Display spinner in multi-module app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336800/angular-http-interceptor-display-spinner-in-multi-module-app)

I tried to use Angular Interceptor as well but this also doesn't give a complete solution because interceptor does its work for each HTTP request and I cannot show and hide the loader for all the request at once. 
The result will be: 
Show
Hide
Show
Hide
Show 
Hide
like this for a load of a single page if I use the interceptor.
  Need some recommendation on what I should do here?

Comment: Have you tried using the HTTP interceptor? That might work if your network requests are not explicitly called at separate times. What does your network request graph look like?

Comment: @nipuna777 - That's the thing, the requests are called separate time. I tried Http Interceptor but it just tracks each request and if I use it then the loader will just keep blinking until all requests are completed. I need to find a way to show the loader once and only hide after there are no network requests left.

Comment: You could increment a counter that keeps the loading requests, then only hide the loading screen when all requests have completed?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you the total thats the way you schould do it, but some ideas to get it.

I would build a queing service that in which you can add all requests and process them.
This service can have a queueStart rxjs subject and queueDone.

With both Subjects you cand handle from outside when you want to start processing and when it's done. At the done you subscribe and stop your spinner. Within the start subject you invoke your spinner. Do this in every component onInit() you need it.