# Angular 5 - spinner HttpInterceptor sometimes takes a long time to disappear after all requests are complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I've recently implemented a spinner which displays when http requests are happening and sometimes it keeps displaying even though all the requests are complete. When this happens the UI is completely blocked because our spinner UI displays on the whole page. When I refresh the spinner displays and disappears quickly (possibly because of cached requests).

Anyway here is my code:

```
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
import { ErrorHandlingService } from '../../service/error-handling.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private count = 0;

  constructor(
    private readonly spinner: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly errorHandling: ErrorHandlingService,
    private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.count++;

    if (this.count === 1) {
      this.spinner.show();
    }

    const handleObs = next.handle(req);

    handleObs
      .catch((err: any) => {
        this.count--;
        return Observable.throw(err);
      })
      .do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.count--;
          if (this.count === 0) {
            this.spinner.hide();
          }
        }
      }).finally(() => {

        this.applicationRef.tick();
      });


    return handleObs;
  }
}
```

Does anyone see anything in my code which would cause this problem? I've looked at other example code and I can't see what is causing my issue.

Comment: If you have only 1 pending request and it will fail - what does spinner show? )

Answer (score 0):

Since it happens inside `do()` it' probably not caught by Angular and is only detected in the next change detection cycle.

You can simply wrap the call with `setTimeout()` because it's monkey-patched by Angular or use `NgZone.run`:

```
.do(event => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count === 0) setTimeout(() => this.spinner.hide());
  }
})
```

Comment: Or don't use hacks like those, and use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` for which it was built.

Comment: On components yes, but not in `HttpInterceptor` because it has no change detection. This isn't a hack by the way.

Comment: @martin I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I also tried this suggestion: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336800/angular-http-interceptor-display-spinner-in-multi-module-app) adding subscribe to the end of the chain but it then does every request twice. However the spinner disappears once all requests are done.

Comment: Oh, well then they should be using `ApplicationRef`. Putting function calls to browser execution queue sure is a hack, and it will be blocked by other functions calls on execution queue, if there are any.

Comment: @ritaj Do you know how I would use ApplicationRef? I'm going to update my post with what I've tried to do (doesn't work).

Comment: It's hard to tell why your Interceptor is not working, maybe you could reproduce it in a simpler example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve