# Show progress spinner by only calling JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular (6) and I want to show up a progress spinner (MatProgressSpinner) without knowing the HTML. When I do a HTTP request, I want to trigger an JavaScript method that shows up the progress spinner. I don't want to define it anywhere in my HTML and it should not be visible in my DOM either, only a showup at runtime.

How can I do this? Really can't find a solution :(

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) (chieffancypants loading bar/wheel)?

Comment: No I mean the Angular Progress Spinner (https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview). I'm using this one, but I don't want to define it in every HTML. I want to show it by using a JavaScript component or something.

Comment: Is it Angular or AngularJS? They are different frameworks. You don't need to define it in every HTML in Angular (I'm not sure what this means, Angular doesn't have 'HTML', it has component templates), only once. There's no magic pill that will make the spinner work for requests. If you want to show it for requests, you need to handle this yourself, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520889/angular4-using-httpclients-interceptor-to-setup-a-spinner

Comment: I'm sorry, it's Angular. I changed the main post to prevent future misunderstandings. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery Modal Loader ;
see https://www.labor.ny.gov/ux/code-modal-loader.html
I hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom loading service like here:
https://github.com/boytsovevg/steamRoom/tree/master/src/app/loading

Or you could implement custom method wrapped your methodWithSpinner

```
private loadingSubject = new Subject<Loading>();
public loadingState = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

public withProgressSpinner<T>(spinnerMethod$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    this.start();

    return spinnerMethod$
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.end())
        );
}

private start(): void {
    this.loadingSubject.next({isLoading: true} as Loading);
}

private end(): void {
    this.loadingSubject.next({isLoading: false} as Loading);
}
```

Feel free to ask questions.